# Utilizar classes do pacote java.util.concurrent para multiplicar matrizes em android?

Tags: android, multithreading, paralelismo

Estava fazendo esse programa para multiplicar matrizes, vi que ele calcula corretamente o resultado, porém não há ganho de performance colocando mais threads, muitas vezes até piora o desempenho apesar de estar rodando em um smartphone 4 quad core. Gostaria de saber se estou fazendo algo muito errado (não sei muito sobre paralelismo) ou este problema não vale tanto a pena ser paralelizado.

O programa foi baseado nesta pergunta : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484204/parallel-matrix-multiplication-in-java-6

Obrigado.

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int SIZE;
private static final int THRESHOLD = 64;
private  int MAX_THREADS;
private double valor;
private ExecutorService executor = null;
private TextView textTamanhoMatrizes;

private TextView multiplicacaoConcluida;
private TextView textQuantidadeThreads;
private TextView textValorElementos;
private EditText valorElementos;
private EditText tamanhoMatrizes;

private EditText quantidadeThreads;
private TextView textTempoExecucao;
private TextView tempoExecucao;
private Button buttonMultiplicarMatrizes;

double matrizA[][] ;
double matrizB[][]; 
double matrizResultante[][];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textTamanhoMatrizes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTamanhoMatrizes);
    textQuantidadeThreads = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textQuantidadeThreads);
    tamanhoMatrizes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tamanhoMatrizes);
    textValorElementos = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textValorElementos);
    quantidadeThreads = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.quantidadeThreads);
    valorElementos = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.valorElementos);
    textTempoExecucao = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTempoExecucao);
    tempoExecucao = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempoExecucao);
    buttonMultiplicarMatrizes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMultiplicarMatrizes);
    multiplicacaoConcluida = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.multiplicacaoConcluida);
    multiplicacaoConcluida.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    textTempoExecucao.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    tempoExecucao.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);        
    buttonMultiplicarMatrizes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SIZE = Integer.valueOf(tamanhoMatrizes.getText().toString());
            MAX_THREADS = Integer.valueOf(quantidadeThreads.getText().toString());
            valor = Double.valueOf(valorElementos.getText().toString());
            matrizA = new double[SIZE][SIZE];
            matrizB = new double[SIZE][SIZE];
            matrizResultante = new double[SIZE][SIZE];
            init(matrizA, matrizB, SIZE, valor);

            executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(SIZE);
            Long tempoInicial =0L;
            Long tempoFinal=0L;
            MatrixMultiplyTask mainTask =  new MatrixMultiplyTask(matrizA, 0, 0, matrizB, 0, 0, matrizResultante, 0, 0, SIZE);
            tempoInicial = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
             Future future = executor.submit(mainTask);  
             try {
                    future.get();
                    tempoFinal = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    multiplicacaoConcluida.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textTempoExecucao.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    tempoExecucao.setText((tempoFinal-tempoInicial)+" ms");
                    tempoExecucao.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Início : "+tempoInicial+" Fim: "+tempoFinal+" Total: "+(tempoFinal-tempoInicial)+ "ms", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            if (matrizA == null || matrizB == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Erro ao gerar matriz A ou matriz B", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

        }
    });


}




      static void init(double[][] matrizA2, double[][] matrizB2, int n, double valor) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            matrizA2[i][j] = valor;
            matrizB2[i][j] = valor;
        }
    }
}

    public class Seq implements Runnable {

    private final MatrixMultiplyTask a;
    private final MatrixMultiplyTask b;

    public Seq(MatrixMultiplyTask a, MatrixMultiplyTask b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;     
    }

    public void run() {
        a.run();
        b.run();
    }   
}




     private class MatrixMultiplyTask implements Runnable {
        private final double[][] A; // Matrix A
        private final int aRow; // first row of current quadrant of A
        private final int aCol; // first column of current quadrant of A

        private final double[][] B; // Similarly for B
        private final int bRow;
        private final int bCol;

        private final double[][] C; // Similarly for result matrix C
        private final int cRow;
        private final int cCol;

        private final int size;

        public MatrixMultiplyTask(double[][] A, int aRow, int aCol, double[][] B,
                int bRow, int bCol, double[][] C, int cRow, int cCol, int size) {

            this.A = A;
            this.aRow = aRow;
            this.aCol = aCol;
            this.B = B;
            this.bRow = bRow;
            this.bCol = bCol;
            this.C = C;
            this.cRow = cRow;
            this.cCol = cCol;
            this.size = size;
        }   

        public void run() {

            //System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

            if (size <= THRESHOLD) {
                multiplyStride2();
            } else {

                int h = size / 2;

                        Seq seq1 = new Seq(new MatrixMultiplyTask(A,
                                aRow, aCol, // A11
                                B, bRow, bCol, // B11
                                C, cRow, cCol, // C11
                                h),

                        new MatrixMultiplyTask(A, aRow, aCol + h, // A12
                                B, bRow + h, bCol, // B21
                                C, cRow, cCol, // C11
                                h));

                        Seq seq2 = new Seq(new MatrixMultiplyTask(A,
                                aRow, aCol, // A11
                                B, bRow, bCol + h, // B12
                                C, cRow, cCol + h, // C12
                                h),

                        new MatrixMultiplyTask(A, aRow, aCol + h, // A12
                                B, bRow + h, bCol + h, // B22
                                C, cRow, cCol + h, // C12
                                h));

                        Seq seq3 = new Seq(new MatrixMultiplyTask(A, aRow
                                + h, aCol, // A21
                                B, bRow, bCol, // B11
                                C, cRow + h, cCol, // C21
                                h),

                        new MatrixMultiplyTask(A, aRow + h, aCol + h, // A22
                                B, bRow + h, bCol, // B21
                                C, cRow + h, cCol, // C21
                                h));

                        Seq seq4 = new Seq(new MatrixMultiplyTask(A, aRow
                                + h, aCol, // A21
                                B, bRow, bCol + h, // B12
                                C, cRow + h, cCol + h, // C22
                                h),

                        new MatrixMultiplyTask(A, aRow + h, aCol + h, // A22
                                B, bRow + h, bCol + h, // B22
                                C, cRow + h, cCol + h, // C22
                                h));            



                final FutureTask s1Task = new FutureTask(seq2, null);
                final FutureTask s2Task = new FutureTask(seq3, null);
                final FutureTask s3Task = new FutureTask(seq4, null);

                executor.execute(s1Task);
                executor.execute(s2Task);
                executor.execute(s3Task);

                seq1.run();
                s1Task.run();
                s2Task.run();
                s3Task.run();

                try {
                    s1Task.get();
                    s2Task.get();
                    s3Task.get();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    executor.shutdownNow();
                }       
            }       
        }       


      public void multiplyStride2() {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j += 2) {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 2) {

                    double[] a0 = A[aRow + i];
                    double[] a1 = A[aRow + i + 1];

                    float s00 = 0.0F;
                    float s01 = 0.0F;
                    float s10 = 0.0F;
                    float s11 = 0.0F;

                    for (int k = 0; k < size; k += 2) {

                        double[] b0 = B[bRow + k];

                        s00 += a0[aCol + k] * b0[bCol + j];
                        s10 += a1[aCol + k] * b0[bCol + j];
                        s01 += a0[aCol + k] * b0[bCol + j + 1];
                        s11 += a1[aCol + k] * b0[bCol + j + 1];

                        double[] b1 = B[bRow + k + 1];

                        s00 += a0[aCol + k + 1] * b1[bCol + j];
                        s10 += a1[aCol + k + 1] * b1[bCol + j];
                        s01 += a0[aCol + k + 1] * b1[bCol + j + 1];
                        s11 += a1[aCol + k + 1] * b1[bCol + j + 1];
                    }

                    C[cRow + i][cCol + j] += s00;
                    C[cRow + i][cCol + j + 1] += s01;
                    C[cRow + i + 1][cCol + j] += s10;
                    C[cRow + i + 1][cCol + j + 1] += s11;
                }
            }           
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro que retire:

```
s1Task.run();
s2Task.run();
s3Task.run();
```

porque essa é a tarefa do executor.

Você está executando a mesma coisa duas vezes.